# Dual monitor freezing issues on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, display-settings

I am currently attempting to connect a monitor to a laptop with a broken screen, the monitor works fine, however when I try to disable the primary laptop screen, or mirror the displays, using system settings, `xrandr` or `lxrandr`, ubuntu freezes, requiring a restart. Any suggestions on how I could change the displays without this freezing?

The monitor is a fujitsu siemens c15-2, and the laptop is a dell inspiron 9400, with ATI RV515 graphics. I am running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try this:  hold down the *FN* key, (3 keys to the left of the spacebar), and while doing that press the *F8* key to toggle between *CRT/LCD*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using the *FN* & *F8* keys to toggle *CRT/LCD*, which still led to freezing. However in order to fix the freezing, I used *CTRL + ALT + F1* to open a virtual console rather than restarting. Upon returning to the desktop, the GUI ran smoothly, with only the monitor display active.

Upon performing a restart, the login screen reverted back to an extended display, but after logging in only one display was active.